# Pass result from DeviceAdminReceiver back to calling activity

Tags: android, android-activity, receiver, device-admin

My activity `(MyActivity.class)` executes the method to set the screen lock as follow:

```
startActivityForResult(Security.setLockscreen(getBaseContext()), 1001);
```

Then my receiver class logs the change to the screen lock as follow:

```
public class MyDeviceAdminReceiver extends DeviceAdminReceiver {
   @Override
   public void onPasswordChanged(Context context, Intent intent) {
        super.onPasswordChanged(context, intent);
        // pass result back to calling activity
        intent = new Intent(context, MyActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        intent.putExtra("pwdChange", true);
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

And then I process the result in the `onActivityResult` method from `MyActivity` class.

Is the above the best way to pass result back to the activity? I noticed the above creates another instance of MyActivity class instead of reusing an existing instance of MyActivity class.

Is there another more efficient way of passing data back to the calling activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution I've found is to use `SharedPreferences` to pass data from a `DeviceAdminReceiver` class to an `Activity` class.

I'm sure there are other working solutions that other experienced developers can post in this thread to share with everyone.

Comment: Using `SharedPreferences` is sufficient for now.